# Cannot position a label relatively to stay at the middle top

Tags: python, android, kivy

[This is the output I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCmqT.png)I am trying to place a label at the very top and centre of the top area(centre top), but when I try to do it it just goes out of the screen.Please help by changing the only code I am writing.
Thanks.
What I tried.

```
.py file:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout


class kivyclass(Widget):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kivyclass()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()





.kv file:
#:import utils kivy.utils

<kivyclass>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#d6fffc')

        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Label:
            id: labcovid
            text: 'Covid-19 Uttarakhand'
            font_size: root.width/15
            font_name: 'vollkorn.ttf'
            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#4a4a4a')
```

this is the output I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two-fold

1. Your root widget is a simple widget that does not handle its children in any way.
2. The `Label` that has the text gets as big as the whole window.

The solution to the first is to make a `FloatLayout` as root widget

```py
class kivyclass(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

and to the second, to add this to your label on the `kv` part

```py
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
```

Comment: Wow! I am actually surprised it helped. Thanks noEmbryo.

Comment: @Chitraksh If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too.. ;o)